# Struggling with timer written in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer

I wrote a program that's suppose to run for hours to do its job, The program has many functions defined and also it functions aren't in order,  the user only sees the timer only when the program goes into the function that's for displaying and then the time freezes because of the other functions, is there a way to display the time all throughout the  program without freezing, the timer also doesn't make it to 60 it goes to 34 and then changes the minutes
change my code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 2.7.11

import timeit,os


Start = timeit.default_timer()


def Func1():
    pass   #This Function has things in it I just put pass to show 

def Func2():
    pass

def Func3():

    End = timeit.default_timer()-Start

    Hours = int(round((End/60**2)))
    Mins  = int(round(End/60))
    Secs  = int(round(End))


    if Secs >= 60 and Mins < 60:
        Mins+=1;
    if Secs > 60:
        Secs=int(round(Secs-60))
    else:
        Secs=0
    if Mins >= 60 and Secs >= 60:
        Hours+=1
        Mins=0;
    if Secs > 60:
        Secs=int(round(Secs-60));
    else:
        Secs=0


    if Hours > 9 and Mins > 9 and Secs > 9:

        Timed = ' Time: %d:%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)
    #

    if Hours > 9 and Mins > 9 and Secs <= 9:

        Timed = ' Time: %d:%d:0%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours > 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs > 9:

        Timed = ' Time: %d:0%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours <= 9 and Mins > 9 and Secs > 9:

        Timed = ' Time: 0%d:%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)
    #
    if Hours <= 9 and Mins > 9 and Secs > 9:

        Timed = ' Time: %0d:%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours > 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs > 9:

        Timed = ' Time: %d:0%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours > 9 and Mins > 9 and Secs <= 9:

        Timed = 'Time: %d:%d:0%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)
    #
    if Hours > 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs <= 9:
        Timed = ' Time: %d:0%d:0%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours <= 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs > 9:
        Timed =' Time: 0%d:0%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)
    #
    if Hours <= 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs > 9:
        Timed =  ' Time: 0%d:0%d:%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)

    if Hours <= 9 and Mins <= 9 and Secs <= 9:
        Timed = ' Time: 0%d:0%d:0%d ' %(Hours,Mins,Secs)



    os.system('clear');print Timed


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        Func3()
        Func1()
        Func2()
```

Comment: If you are using hours of CPU time, I'm not sure that Python is a good fit.

Comment: You're using the completely wrong library for the task. If you use [the datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) you'll find it a better fit, and it will do conversion computations for you also.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a couple of problems and it would be great if you could post all the relevant code. For the first problem that your timer resets, you could do something like this instead, where you always keep the start variable in memory and don't overwrite it, and then just ping for time_elapsed = end- start whenever you want the time elapsed(that way it won't get reset accidentally which sounds like what is happening to you).

```
import time

start = time.time()
print("hello")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Now you've stored start time in memory, you can always overwrite the end variable and get the updated time without worrying about the timer stopping and restarting.

Also for the second part of your problem regarding your Func3(), you could do something like this which does only a single division for quotient and remainder to be more efficient. This should give you the accurate time elapsed in HH:MM::SS.

```
time_elapsed = end - start
Mins, Secs = divmod(time_elapsed, 60)
Hours, Mins = divmod(Mins, 60)
print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (Hours, Mins, Secs)
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work correctly, because the timer does start from zero it start at like 54 minutes and also the hours is a negative

Comment: It doesn't need to start at zero, it starts at the current time. You are just measuring a time difference from the start yes?